# Proof of $f(x) - f(y) \geq f'(y)(x-y)$

Tags: analysis, functions, proof-writing

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two times differentiable with $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

How can one prove that $f(x) - f(y) \geq f'(y)(x-y)$?

Comment: Your example does  not satisfy the hypothesis $f''(x) \geq 0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f''(x) \geq 0$ implies that $f'$ is monotonically increasing. Suppose $x >y$. By MVT $f(x)-f(y) =(x-y)f'(u)$ for some $u \in (y,x)$ and the inequality follows from the fact that $f'(u) \geq f'(y)$. Similar argument works when $x <y$.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality $f(x)-f(y)\geqslant f'(y)(x-y)$ holds under the assumption that $x>y$. In fact, $f(x)-f(y)=f'(c)(x-y)$ for some $c\in(y,x)$ and, since $f'$ is increasing, $f'(c)\geqslant f'(y)$.

Comment: It holds for $x \le y$ as well. (The graph of a convex function lies above a tangent line at the graph.)